# can anyone tell how to run udp client server program in sunsolaris system?

Tags: c, udp, solaris, solaris-10

program has no errors but i am unable to execute the prog it is showing segmentation fault 
can anyone tell the syntax for executing the client server program in linux and sun sorlaris also.

Comment: That wouldn't cause a seg fault, though.  Sounds like a bug.

Comment: Why the tag for linux, when you ask a question about solaris?

Answer (score 1):

I have a very simple UDP client-server program that's working fine on my Ubuntu machine.
It's a very minimal program with no error checking and precautions and it's definitely not the way to write.
Server code:

```
#define MAXLINE 255
#define MYPORT 9100
int main()
{
int listenfd,msglen,clientlen;
char buff[MAXLINE];
struct sockaddr_in servaddr,client;
listenfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
servaddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
servaddr.sin_port=htons(MYPORT);
bind(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
clientlen=sizeof(client);
printf("Server is listening");
while(1)
{
msglen=recvfrom(listenfd,buff,100,0,(struct sockaddr *)&client,&clientlen);
buff[msglen]='\0';
sendto(listenfd,buff,msglen,0,(struct   sockaddr*)&client,clientlen);
}
}
```

Client code:

```
#define MAXLINE 255
#define SERV_PORT 9100
#define SA struct sockaddr
int main()
{
char send[100],recv[100];
int sockfd,len;
struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
servaddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
servaddr.sin_port=htons(SERV_PORT);
inet_pton(AF_INET,"127.0.0.1",&servaddr.sin_addr);
memset((&servaddr.sin_zero),'\0',8);
while(1)
{
printf("Type your message:");
fgets(send,100,stdin);
sendto(sockfd,send,strlen(send),0,(SA*) &servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
if((len=recvfrom(sockfd,recv,100,0,(SA*)NULL,NULL))>0)
{
recv[len]='\0';
printf("Server echo:%s\n",recv);
}
}
close(sockfd);
}
```

Include the necessary header files. 
sys/types.h
sys/socket.h
netinet/in.h
stdlib.h
stdio.h